# Rapture according to Mid-Tribulation Theory

Tags: biblical-basis, eschatology, rapture, premillennialism, tribulation

I am working on writing a blog post about the rapture and am curious about the different theories of the rapture. Could someone explain to me the Mid-Tribulation Rapture theory and show some supporting verses for it, as given by those who support this theory? I previously asked about the Pre-Tribulation theory [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/57792/rapture-according-to-pre-trib-theory).

Comment: If you share the ways that (for example) [Wikipedia's treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapture#Timing) is insufficient, that will improve the quality of your question and, most likely, the quality of the answers you receive.

Comment: If you hover over the vote buttons on questions you'll see the primary suggestion for how to vote has to do with research effort. Questions that show no effort has been put into reading what is already readily available do not tend to produce answers with valuable material. At best answers tend to just rehash basic material from the relevant Wikipedia articles in a less refined format! If you want experts to answer your questions please do some basic research yourself before asking then bring us specific questions which might require expertise to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mid Tribulation teaches the rapture will happen 3 1/2 years into the Tribulation, and for those who are not raptured, they are here for the rest of the 3 1/2 years of the Tribulation. Once all 7 years end of the Tribulation, then Jesus will come again. That is most of the things I know about it.
Glory to God.

Comment: Good answer, except you are missing supporting verses. Add the verses and preferably expand your answer and I may accept it as the best answer

Comment: Without looking up verses, I guess it is because Jesus says things talking about the end times like, "How bad will it be for women who are nursing in those days." And "Do not go back for your coat" and He talks about really bad things going on. If he told it to the disciples, it must be for any Christian if it is a future event like that. But in other places it says, such as in Revelation that if one of the churches stays strong to the end, then He will deliver them from the hour of trial. So it is probably bounce back and forth verses like that.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear to me that the Rapture will be Mid-Trib.

Rev. 10:11 says:

> And he said unto me, Thou must prophesy *again* before many peoples, and nations, and tongues, and kings. (emphasis added)

Therefore, the "Rise" in the next verse (Rev. 11:1) is the Mid-Trib Rapture when Moses and Elijah return.

Rev. 11:1-3 says:

> And there was given me a reed like unto a rod: and the angel stood, saying, Rise, and measure the temple of God, and the altar, and them that worship therein. 2 But the court which is without the temple leave out, and measure it not; for it is given unto the Gentiles: and the holy city shall they tread under foot forty and two months. 3 And I will give power unto my two witnesses, and they shall prophesy a thousand two hundred and threescore days, clothed in sackcloth.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Comment: The OP asked for an explanation of Mid-Tribulation theory. Could you add that to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is more proof:

> Rev 12:6  And the woman fled into the wilderness, where she hath a place prepared of God, that they should feed her there a thousand two hundred and threescore days. 
>   Rev 12:7  And there was war in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against the dragon; and the dragon fought and his angels, 
>   Rev 12:8  And prevailed not; neither was their place found any more in heaven. 
>   Rev 12:9  And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: he was cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him. 
>   Rev 12:10  And I heard a loud voice saying in heaven, NOW IS COME SALVATION [*soteria,* rescue, i.e., the Mid-Trib Rapture], and strength, and the kingdom of our God, and the power of his Christ: for the accuser of our brethren is cast down, which accused them before our God day and night. 
>   Rev 12:11  And they overcame him by the blood of the Lamb, and by the word of their testimony; and they loved not their lives unto the death. 
>   Rev 12:12  Therefore rejoice, ye heavens, and ye that dwell in them."

Comment: This answer would be much better if you provided some commentary on how these verses support Mid-Tribulation Rapture theory. Answers that provide Bible verses only, without any commentary, are not considered good answers here. For some tips on writing good answers, see: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/20394)

Comment: Is this intended to expand on your other answer? Is so, it should be edited into that first answer.

Comment: Interesting, I agree with the first two comments on this answer. Needs some explaining. If this does go along with the Mid Trib Rapture theory, and the sign mentioned is really about to happen, could the Rapture be right around the corner? Just an idea